# Rails cookie_store working on localhost but not Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Using localhost, I'm able to get a cookie back upon authentication.

However, uploading that exact same working code to heroku and running that same request does not return a cookie.

**session_store.rb**

```
Pager::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_pager_session', :domain => :all
```

I'm using a custom domain for my heroku app, `pager.mydomain.com`.

I wish I could give more information, but I have no clue where to even begin debugging this thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding

```
config.api_only = false
```

in `production.rb` solved my issue.